# How to read data in blocks/chunks from CSV file in JMeter for the subsequent POSTs

Tags: jmeter

I have say, 1000 users, each user needs to read 50 unique data from a CSV file and POST in the subsequent JSON API call. For example, data file looks like: 
[image]
User-1 will have to read 50 data from D1 to D50, User-2 will read the next 50 data from D51 to D100 and so on.
As there are thousands of data, I cant have the data file like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an "exotic" use case for the CSV Data Set Config, the only way I can see is using i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines()[(ctx.getThreadNum()) * 50..((ctx.getThreadNum()) * 50)+50].join('\n'),)}
```

Where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html), check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for JSR223 scripts

Comment: I have done this by adding a loop controller with 50 times, added a counter for 50 for using in the subsequent BeanShell sampler like:   vars.put("D_${Counter}", vars.get("D")); AFTER reading the CSV file into a variable D